# Is there a flag when nexus yum repo metadata build is complete?

Tags: nexus, yum

We’re using Sonatype Nexus 2.14.x and our CI-CD pipelines are breaking because a heavily written to repo is slow to generate metadata in time for the yum install test stage. I’d like to have a “pause until metadata build done” step but can’t quite find something to wait on. REST api docs are literally nonexistent and spelunking the nexus oss source doesn’t seem to show a REST flag for this.